# Java ProcessBuilder process.destroy() not killing child processes in winXP

Tags: java

I have a java app that uses `ProcessBuilder` to prepare an operating system command and gives me a `Process` object. (The actual os command is rsync over ssh using cygwin).

This is working well in Windows, however if I want to stop the process using `process.destroy()` it will not kill the child ssh and rsync processes.....
I have to manually kill them using the windows task manager..

Is it possible to get the `OutputStream` of the process and send a ctrl-c somehow before I call `destroy();`?

If anyone has any ideas on a workaround it would be great.
Thanks,
D

Comment: The Ctrl-C is a terminal function that sends a signal (SIGTERM?) to the process id. So to emulate that you'd need the process id and to be able to send a signal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also think that emulating Ctrl-C in order to kill ssh entirely is problematic.

What I would do, is one of the following approaches. Either use windows commands to find out who are ssh's sons (which is a little bit problematic, since you need to know your current pid in order to recieve your own children-processes). I believe [pstools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) of sysinternals is a good command-line tool that should enable you to track orphan processes. See [this example](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0593.html) for controlling windows processes either with `taskList.exe` (which can give you its output in CSV format BTW) or by executing a special VBScript.

The second approach is using a java library such as [winp](http://winp.kohsuke.org/) to execute and control the ssh process. I believe you'd be able to list all its children and forcibly kill them if sending the correct message would not suffice. This would be my preferred approach. Please note that the [killRecursively](https://winp.dev.java.net/nonav/apidocs/org/jvnet/winp/WinProcess.html#killRecursively()) method does exactly what you want.

Please note that those approaches should not render your application windows only. You can encapsulate those in a class that would run differently on Windows and linux machines.

Please note I didn't try to gain a fine-grained control on windows processes with, so I'm not sure how mature would those solutions I found are.

Comment: winp seems to have grown in popularity, and is part of Hudson (actually, was written for it).  The java.net URL doesn't resolve any more, but the original article still exists at https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2008/03/introducing_win.html (note that some of that info is dated, like only 32bit).  The  new URL for winp (with links to mvn and github) is:  http://winp.kohsuke.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what Process.destroy() does under the covers (sends a signal or similar?).

What you may find works better is to invoke your ssh/rsync within a shell script, and have that return a process id on stdout, and then when you want to kill the process, perform a `/bin/kill` with that process id. A little messy, but perhaps more reliable.

Note you can `/bin/kill` with SIGTERM, and SIGKILL if it's particularly stubborn.

Comment: Process.destroy() calls the Windows function TerminateProcess (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714(VS.85).aspx ).