# Process.destroy is not working

Tags: java, xcode, automation

Im trying to kill a process from my JAVA code:

```
    File file = new File("c://test//test.jar");
    String folderToFile = file.getAbsolutePath();
    String filePath = folderToFile.substring(0,folderToFile.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
    String[] cmd = String.format("cmd /c java -jar %s", file.getName()).split(" ");
    Process pSimulator = (new ProcessBuilder(cmd))
            .directory(new File(filePath))
            .redirectErrorStream(true)
            .start();

    Thread.sleep(300);
    pSimulator.destroy();
```

I don't know why but the process that i'm trying to kill remains open...
the "test.jar" that i'm running here is just a rendom jar that i've picked on the web...

any ideas?

Comment: Try using `pSimulator.waitFor();` before the `pSimulator.destroy();`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-4770092) in Java's Process.destroy() implementation on Windows. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5148641/3405171).

You can try to use [Apache Commons Exec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html).

Comment: Does ```java -jar %s``` work instead of ```cmd /c java -jar %s```?