# I want to close a windows process started by my java program from java only

Tags: java, swing

I Tried the following code , no exception is raised but the opendhcpserver program does not stop, even tried debugging but still no clue. Using this command to run the program

```
Process p= new Precess();
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C C:\\OpenDHCPServer\\OpenDHCPServer.exe -v");
```

using this to close

```
p.destroy();
```

Comment: Why not just `exec("C:\\OpenDHCPServer\\OpenDHCPServer.exe -v")`?

Comment: Please don't use `\\ ` (or `\ `) in your command-line paths on Windows.  It hasn't been required for some time now.  Windows has supported `/` in filesystem paths since the days of XP.

Comment: You would like to see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801609/java-processbuilder-process-destroy-not-killing-child-processes-in-winxp

Comment: @daniel that still wont solve my problem of closing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing Process is abstract class you cant instantiate it,

Use Separate methods to start & stop an application, so that when you execute start method it will start the application & when you execute stop method it will stop application. Then it will work as you think.

Comment: I have put the two commands on diffrent functions but still now i use
Process p;
Start Button
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\OpenDHCPServer\\OpenDHCPServer.exe -v"); 
Stop button 
p.destroy();
but still the process started by windowns for OpenDHCPServer still remains

Comment: no exceptions are thrown ...... can there be a way to provide teh instance running the process a Ctrl+c to stop it???